# How to pass authorization token in every request

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

After the user logs in I verify their info and generate a JWT token.

Authentication process happens with `Authentication` (it's not my custom handler).

Where and how do I save this token so it will be sent along the http calls? I don't want to save it in the client side because of XSS attacks. The following doesn't seem to work either as I wont be in every request

```
  HttpContext.Request.Headers.Append("Authorization", MyGeneratedJWTTokenAsString);
```

I have found answers that use `HttpClient.Request` but is there any other secure way of doing this?

Comment: Could you clarify? What exactly do you want to do with the token? You want it saved so you can use it to make requests from within the service using `HttpClient`?

Comment: I want to always have it in calls once authenticated. calls are made in react, requesting data from the api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `HttpClient` in a backend service, it is always good to use the `IHttpClientFactory` to generate clients.

So, what we are going to do is use this factory (in conjunction with `IHttpContextAccessor`) to produce `HttpClient` objects that have the current user's authorization scheme and token. So, add this to your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddHttpClient("UserAuthorizedHttpClient", (sp, httpClient) =>
    {
        var accessor = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

        if (accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(
            "Authorization", out var authHeaderValue) &&
                AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(
                    authHeaderValue, out var auth))
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue(auth.Scheme, auth.Parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            // incase there is a value from a previous generation
            if(httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            }
        }
    });

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    // ...
}
```

In order to use these special clients, you simply inject `IHttpClientFactory` in to the service that needs to make the HTTP requests:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YouApplicationNamespace.Services
{
    public interface IMyHttpRequesterService
    {
        Task DoSomethingCoolAsync();
    }

    public sealed class MyHttpRequesterService : IMyHttpRequesterService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public MyHttpRequesterService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) =>
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;

        public async Task DoSomethingCoolAsync()
        {
            var authroizedHttpClient =
                _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("UserAuthorizedHttpClient");

            var resp = await authroizedHttpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://www.example.com/"));

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

As long as you use the same name, you will get a client that uses the `AddHttpClient` routine in your configuration.

(Please note: this code is not tested. It is more of a guideline)

Comment: @iamaaarianme -- no problem! if you need any help with this, i'm always around.